# How can I stop TweetDeck automatically updating?

Tags: adobe-air, tweetdeck

I've looked at all the options and can't seem to find anything. Now I'm stuck with the regular occurrence of an empty TweetDeck window, in addition to the normal TweetDeck window, that just has the title "Updating: TweeDeck", and does nothing. I'm worried that it might me using bandwidth resources I would really rather not be used.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday, the @TweetDeck Twitter account tweeted [a response](http://twitter.com/#!/TweetDeck/status/123779867434172416) that solved the problem for me:

> If you see a blank "Updating" window in your Desktop TweetDeck, simply update manually by downloading from j.mp/cMVFMl

The j.mp URL links to http://www.tweetdeck.com/desktop/.

Answer (score 1):

TweetDeck has no options in its settings to control automatic updates. It automatically checks and applies the updates. There is a glitch in your case, and I recommend you uninstalling TweetDeck completely, and reinstalling it from scratch. You can use [Revo Uninstaller (Free version)](http://www.revouninstaller.com/start_freeware_download.html) to *completely* uninstall it.